# How can I choose a function at compile time based on a constexpr result

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a function that does work on dynamic data (many_things) at run time:

```
void do_some_work(Thing &many_things)
{
    constexpr bool add = something_evald_at_compile_time;

    // do some work
    for(auto &thing : many_things) {
        thing.result = add_or_subtract(thing.one,thing.two);
    }
}
```

I want to have two variants of 'add_or_subtract' and call one or the other based on the constexpr 'add':

```
template <typename N> // call me if 'add' == true
N add_or_subtract(N a, N b) { return a+b; }

template <typename N> // call me if 'add' == false
N add_or_subtract(N a, N b) { return a-b; }
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a helper type.

```
template <bool val=true> struct is_add {};
template <> struct is_add<false> {};
```

Use the helper type to differentiate between add and subtract.

```
template <typename N> // call me if 'add' == true
N add_or_subtract(N a, N b, is_add<true>) { return a+b; }

template <typename N> // call me if 'add' == false
N add_or_subtract(N a, N b, is_add<false>) { return a-b; }
```

Usage:

```
void do_some_work(Thing &many_things)
{
    constexpr bool add = something_evald_at_compile_time;

    // do some work
    for(auto &thing : many_things) {
        thing.result = add_or_subtract(thing.one,thing.two, is_add<add>());
    }
}
```

With C++17 you may look into [`if constexpr()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if).

Comment: Will this code always determine which add_or_subtract to call only once during compile time (in a non compiler dependent way)? Are there any advantages/disadvantages compared to @Deduplicator's method?

Comment: @Pris, yes. Advantage: no run time cost. Disadvantage, you need a bit more code. I am not sure what's the cost of compiling code that depends on template meta programming.

Comment: I went with this because its a bit more clear that templates are being used to try and avoid run-time checks. Both answers are valid though.

Answer (score 2):

Just use a conditional on that compile-time-evaluated expression:

```
template <typename N> // call me if 'add' == true
N add(N a, N b) { return a+b; }

template <typename N> // call me if 'add' == false
N subtract(N a, N b) { return a-b; }

void do_some_work(Thing &many_things)
{
    constexpr bool do_add = something_evald_at_compile_time;

    // do some work
    for(auto &thing : many_things)
        thing.result = (do_add ? add : subtract)(thing.one,thing.two);
}
```

Comment: Will this code always determine which add_or_subtract to call only once during compile time (in a non compiler dependent way)? Isn't it possible for constexpr to not be evaluated at compile time? Are there any advantages/disadvantages compared to @R Sahu's method?

Comment: While a `constexpr` function could (though should not be if avoidable) be evaluated at runtime, a `constexpr` variable has to be at compile-time. And standard constant-propagation will eliminate the conditional.